# How can i compare two rows of datatable in QTP

Tags: testing, automation, qtp

How can i compare two rows of datatable  in QTP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Do you want to compare data rows in QTP's native DataTable object?

- Use SetCurrentRow method 
  Example: objDataSheet.SetCurrentRow(intRow)
- Use GetParameter to access column name and cell value
  sColName = objDataSheet.GetParameter(j).Name
  Value by index: sCellValue = objDataSheet.GetParameter(j).Name
  Value by col name: sCellValue = objDataSheet.GetParameter(sColName).Name

2) Do you want to compare 2 rows in 2 distinct Excel worksheets?
You can use the following code (taken from my blog http://automationbeyond.wordpress.com , see other examples too)

Excel application must be installed on the PC.
Comparison goes cell by cell within the occupied range.
Mismatching cells are marked red.

Both workbooks must exist and be defined as the full path with file.
Both worksheets must exist and may be defined as a numeric index or string name.

objParameter is a reserved parameter to implement custom comparison like “ignore case”, “round up numbers”, etc.

```
Public Function ExcelWorksheetCompare(ByVal sWorkbook1, ByVal sWorksheet1, ByVal sWorkbook2, ByVal sWorksheet2, ByVal objParameter)
Dim boolRC, boolSheetExists
Dim FSO, XLHandle
Dim XLBook1, XLBook2, XLSheet1, XLSheet2
Dim Iter, objCell

‘Verify both files exist
Set FSO = CreateObject(”Scripting.FileSystemObject”)
boolRC = FSO.FileExists(sWorkbook1)
If Not boolRC Then
ExcelWorksheetCompare = FALSE
Exit Function
End If
boolRC = FSO.FileExists(sWorkbook2)
If Not boolRC Then
ExcelWorksheetCompare = FALSE
Exit Function
End If
Set FSO = Nothing

Set XLHandle = CreateObject(”Excel.Application”)
XLHandle.DisplayAlerts = False

‘Open workbook1
Set XLBook1 = XLHandle.WorkBooks.Open(sWorkbook1)

‘Verify sheet exists (1)
If isNumeric(sWorksheet1) Then
sWorksheet1 = CInt(sWorksheet1)
If (sWorksheet1 &gt;0) AND (sWorksheet1&lt;=XLBook1.Worksheets.Count) Then
Set XLSheet1 = XLBook1.Worksheets(sWorksheet1)
boolSheetExists = TRUE
Else
boolSheetExists = FALSE
End If
Else
boolSheetExists = FALSE
For Iter = 1To XLBook1.Worksheets.Count
If XLBook1.Worksheets(Iter).Name = sWorksheet1 Then
Set XLSheet1 = XLBook1.Worksheets(Iter)
boolSheetExists = TRUE
End If
Next
End If

If Not boolSheetExists Then
XLBook1.Close
XLHandle.Quit
Set XLBook1 = Nothing
Set XLHandle = Nothing

ExcelWorksheetCompare = FALSE
Exit Function
End If

‘Open workbook2
Set XLBook2 = XLHandle.WorkBooks.Open(sWorkbook2)

‘Verify sheet exists (2)
If isNumeric(sWorksheet2) Then
sWorksheet2 = CInt(sWorksheet2)
If (sWorksheet2 &gt;0) AND (sWorksheet2&lt;=XLBook2.Worksheets.Count) Then
Set XLSheet2 = XLBook2.Worksheets(sWorksheet2)
boolSheetExists = TRUE
Else
boolSheetExists = FALSE
End If
Else
boolSheetExists = FALSE
For Iter = 1To XLBook2.Worksheets.Count
If XLBook2.Worksheets(Iter).Name = sWorksheet2 Then
Set XLSheet2 = XLBook2.Worksheets(Iter)
boolSheetExists = TRUE
End If
Next
End If

If Not boolSheetExists Then
XLBook1.Close
XLBook2.Close
XLHandle.Quit
Set XLSheet1 = Nothing
Set XLBook1 = Nothing
Set XLBook2 = Nothing
Set XLHandle = Nothing

ExcelWorksheetCompare = FALSE
Exit Function
End If

‘Mark range

‘Compare and mark mismatches red
For Each objCell In XLSheet2.UsedRange
If objCell.Value &lt;&gt; XLSheet1.Range(objCell.Address).Value Then
objCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
Else
objCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End If
Next

‘Save and close

XLBook1.Close

XLBook2.Save
XLBook2.Close

XLHandle.Quit

Set XLSheet1 = Nothing
Set XLSheet2 = Nothing
Set XLBook1 = Nothing
Set XLBook2 = Nothing
Set XLHandle = Nothing

ExcelWorksheetCompare = TRUE

End Function
```